# создание словаря из координат точек и их значений

Tags: python-3.x

Как создать словарь значений в котором ключи это координата точки в матрице, а значение ключа это соответственно значение точки в этой координате?

Comment: `{(3, 4): 567}`

Comment: или так {3: {4: 567}}

Comment: @andreymal
Странно я также делал и думал что ошибка в составление как раз словаря, а  вы случайно не знаете почему может тогда выдавать подобную ошибку

m[a1.keys()]=1
IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices

m это в данном случае матрица нулей m = np.zeros((4,3))

Comment: А с numpy это уже абсолютно другая история, надо было упомянуть это в вопросе